# Convert string array into object with same key/value

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

How do I convert `["one","two","three"]` into `{one:"one", two:"two", three:"three"}`

```
import stringArray from './a.js';

class b {
 hashmap = stringArray// convert this into Object here inline.
}
```

Before you jump I know of for how to achieve this in say constructor() with tricks like forEach, for in loop etc. Is there a simple one line code to achieve this in the class property not inside a function.

Comment: `stringArray.reduce((a, c) => (a[c] = c, a), {})`

Comment: You can also use an **IIFE**, for example: `hashmap = (() => {.. return "something"})()`

Answer (score 2):

## Lodash

You can use [`_.zipObject`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#zipObject). It accepts two arrays - one for keys, another for values but if you just use the same array twice you'd get matching pairs:

```js
const arr = ["one","two","three"];

const obj = _.zipObject(arr, arr);
console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

## Plain JavaScript

You can use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to do the same thing. It works with an array of key-value pairs, so you'll have to transform yours to that:

```js
const arr = ["one","two","three"];

const matchingKeyValuePairs = arr.map(x => [x, x]);

const obj = Object.fromEntries(matchingKeyValuePairs);
console.log(obj);
```

Also you can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate an object with a computed property name:

```js
const arr = ["one","two","three"];

const obj = arr.reduce((acc, item) => ({...acc, [item]: item}), {});
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I am trying to do it in class member declaration so multi line code won't work. But I will go with your answer if you change it

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to add the array as properties to the current instance?

Comment: class b {
          hashmap = _.zipObject(arr, arr);
    }

Comment: Why does it matter what are you assigning to? You're interested in the data being correct - whether you produce a variable or an object property or whatever, the [the result is the same](https://jsbin.com/qunuxokize/edit?js,console)

Comment: It doesn't in this case but it will with other multiline code cases.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what the issue is. [Object.entries](https://jsbin.com/dojerutoyo/edit?js,console) and [reduce](https://jsbin.com/tobalidawi/2/edit?js,console) both work. What is the issue with multilines?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const arr = ["one","two","three"]
let obj = {}
arr.forEach(item => {obj[item] = item})
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
data = ["one","two","three"];
data = data.map(e => [e,e]) // keyvalue pairs [["one","one"],["two","two"],["three","three"]]
data = Object.fromEntries(data); // {"one":"one","two":"two","three":"three"}
```

`map` will convert each element of your input array to a structure you want.

In this case, we want to convert each element to an array with the element repeated twice in it

`Object.froEntries` will convert a list of key-value pair to an `Object`

***This can be also done with the plain old for loop***

```js
data = ["one","two","three"];
obj = {};
for(let i = 0; i < data.length ; i++){
   obj[data[i]] = data[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lodash has the [`_.keyBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#keyBy) function, that creates an object from an array by generating keys from the values via the function supplied (the iteratee). The default iteratee is `_.identity()`, which returns the value.

```js
const arr = ["one","two","three"];

const obj = _.keyBy(arr);

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```